# Terraform decouple Security Group dependency

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-security-group

This is tested with **Terraform v0.12.9**

I generally manage security groups and security group rules as separate resources, as in the below example:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "this" {
  count       = var.create ? 1 : 0
  name_prefix = "${var.security_group_name}_"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress_rules" {
  count                     = var.create ? length(var.inbound_security_group_ids) : 0

  security_group_id         = aws_security_group.this[0].id
  type                      = "ingress"

  from_port                 = var.from_port
  to_port                   = var.to_port
  protocol                  = "tcp"
  source_security_group_id  = var.inbound_security_group_ids[count.index]
}
```

The implementation for this would look something like the below:

```
module "test_module" {
  source                     = "../path/to/module/"

  create                     = true
  vpc_id                     = "vpc-xxxxxx"
  security_group_name        = "${var.service_name}-db"
  from_port                  = 1234
  to_port                    = 1234
  inbound_security_group_ids = [
    module.service.security_group_id_one,
    module.service.security_group_id_two
  ]
}
```

**Problem**

I want this to work if the outputs from the `module.service` aren't created.  In that scenario my expectation is that `length(var.inbound_security_group_ids)` should evaluate to `0` resulting in the security group rules not being created

What actually happens is that `length(var.inbound_security_group_ids)` evaluates to `2` when `module.service` isn't created.  This is presumably because it is an array of two blank strings `["", ""]`

According to the [Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/compact.html) I can handle this with the `compact` function, which removes empty strings from an array.

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress_rules" {
  count                     = var.create ? length(compact(var.inbound_security_group_ids)) : 0

  security_group_id         = aws_security_group.this[0].id
  type                      = "ingress"

  from_port                 = var.from_port
  to_port                   = var.to_port
  protocol                  = "tcp"
  source_security_group_id  = var.inbound_security_group_ids[count.index]
}
```

The problem with this, however, is that Terraform is unable to determine the `plan` because it doesn't know what `var.inbound_security_group_ids` evaluates to until `apply-time`.  This is the error message (for context):

> The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
>   until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
>   To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the
>   resources that the count depends on.

**Question**

Is it possible to decouple a security group like this so that it will still be created even when the `source_security_group_id` attribute has no values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's often easier to work with lists or sets that might be empty in Terraform than to work with individual values that might not be set, for a reason related to what you've observed: it separates whether the value is set from what the value actually is, so that the *presence* of the value can be known even if the value itself isn't known.

In this case, you might approach that by changing how you return the security group ids from your `service` module, so that each of those outputs is a *list* of security group ids rather than a single string that might be either a valid security group id or an empty string:

```
module "test_module" {
  source                     = "../path/to/module/"

  create                     = true
  vpc_id                     = "vpc-xxxxxx"
  security_group_name        = "${var.service_name}-db"
  from_port                  = 1234
  to_port                    = 1234
  inbound_security_group_ids = concat(
    module.service.security_group_ids_one,
    module.service.security_group_ids_two,
  )
}
```

If either `security_group_ids_one` or `security_group_ids_two` is known to be an empty list then `concat` will ignore it entirely. If they *are* enabled then you can arrange for them to be a known list with one element whose value is unknown, and thus `length(var.inbound_security_group_ids)` will still have a known value in all cases.