# GCP List vm instances and Get External IPs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am at wits end searching for several days now, I am no terraform expert but I cant seem to find anyway to get all the GCP Vm instance List of external ips inside of a Kubernetes cluster as i then need to use this list to add them to allowed list for Database access.

Can someone point me to an example or what

tried something like this but cant use * =\

```
data "google_compute_instance" "instances" {
}

output "instance_ids" {
  value = "${data.google_compute_instance.instances.*.network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip }"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with one way to do this using Terraform, but it's slightly hacky as it involves a bit of string manipulation on some of the URLs due to the GKE cluster metadata returning a list of Instance Group *Managers* and not Instance Groups (despite what the attribute is labelled). However it does work for the cluster I tested it on.

If it helps, here's a Terraform example that outputs the external IPs for all the nodes compute instances:

```
provider "google" {
  version = "~> 2"
  project  = "my-project"
}

// GKE cluster details
data "google_container_cluster" "my_cluster" {
  name     = "my-cluster-name"
  location = "my-location"
} 

// GKE node instance group details
data "google_compute_instance_group" "node_instance_groups" {
    for_each = toset(data.google_container_cluster.my_cluster.node_pool[0].instance_group_urls)
    self_link = replace(each.key, "instanceGroupManagers", "instanceGroups")
}

// GKE node compute instance details
data "google_compute_instance" "nodes" {
    for_each = toset(flatten([for x in data.google_compute_instance_group.node_instance_groups : x.instances[*]]))
    self_link = each.key
}

// Return the external IPs for all GKE node instances
output "external_ips" {
    value = [for x in data.google_compute_instance.nodes : x.network_interface[0].access_config[0].nat_ip]
}
```

Comment: that worked well! thank you but the downside is I can't use it if it depends on another resource. Even if i add depends_on I get      The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the
resources that the for_each depends on.

Comment: It's hard to say what the solution to that might be without seeing your code, maybe post a new question with what you're trying to get working. Also see if this answer provides any help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58607536/terraform-decouple-security-group-dependency?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 0):

Rather than think about the reality that GKE nodes are implemented as Compute Engines, maybe think about GKE nodes in their Kubernetes concept.  As a test, I created a cluster with 3 nodes and then ran:

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

The result was

```
NAME                                STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION           INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP      OS-IMAGE                             KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
gke-c1-default-pool-5b6b460a-59nb   Ready    <none>   68s   v1.13.11-gke.14   10.128.0.42   35.222.104.41    Container-Optimized OS from Google   4.14.138+        docker://18.9.7
gke-c1-default-pool-5b6b460a-ggh9   Ready    <none>   68s   v1.13.11-gke.14   10.128.0.41   35.192.152.130   Container-Optimized OS from Google   4.14.138+        docker://18.9.7
gke-c1-default-pool-5b6b460a-j8nn   Ready    <none>   67s   v1.13.11-gke.14   10.128.0.40   104.197.68.223   Container-Optimized OS from Google   4.14.138+        docker://18.9.7
```

Please pay attention to the column called EXTERNAL-IP.  I then compared these against the Compute Engine VM instance exposed public IP and found them to be identical.

Now that we see that examining the nodes using kubectl returns the information we desire, we can now potentially use a Terraform equivalent to this command.  For example, the [Kubernetes Provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/index.html).

Comment: While this is a nice idea, there's no relevant data source in the Kubernetes provider that will help with this so it's a non starter as things stand right now. You could instead use an external data source to call `kubectl` and output that but you'd need to flesh that out in your answer because that's a bit tricky to leave as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

My terraform knowledge is a little haisy but can you not do the following?

As mentioned on this page: https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html

```
resource "gcp_instance" "web" {
  # ...

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo gcloud compute instances list --format=\"value(External IP)\" --filter=\"name~'gke-$cluster_name-$pool_name*' --format=\"value(External_IP)\" "} >> public_ips.txt"
  }
}
```

then read it from the file?

Comment: Interesting, with the new version of TF i wanted to see if i could use expressions to iterate through the list of ips and create a map.  I will explore these ideas that were posted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The sortest solution to this problem is by using the gcloud command-line tool in conjunction with awk to manipulate the output.

With 2 simple commands, you get a nice formatted output.

First, calculate the number of nodes:

```
num_nodes=$(kubectl get nodes | awk 'END{print NR - 1}')
```

After

```
gcloud compute instances list | awk '{print $1,$5}' | tail -n $num_nodes
```

If you want to create a dynamic Ansible inventory, then the above command becomes:

```
gcloud compute instances list | awk '{print $1, "ansible_ssh_host="$5}' | tail -n $num_nodes
```